# Reset display resolution from console in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, xorg, linux-mint, console

I have a Linux Mint 13 Xfce in a VMware Workstation 8 VM and set the resolution from 800x600 to 1280x768 and now I get permanently logged out when I try to login.
I knew how to get back to my old resolution back in the `xorg.conf` days but Linux Mint now uses `xrandr` which won't display any displays when running it because X is not running (of course not - I can't login over GUI).

I know that there are configuration files in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` because I configured a debian based thinclient's resolution in a file called `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/91configure_display` but that file doesn't exist in my Linux Mint VM.

So, how do I reset my X screen resolution from console?

**Edit:** I forgot to tell you that I can't change resolution in console:

```
# xrandr -s 800x600
Can't open display
```

This message appears every time I use `xrandr` or `xrandr -s *resolution*`.

**Update:** I tried what bWowk suggested:

```
# export DISPLAY=:0.0
# xrandr -s 800x600
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Can't open display :0.0
```

So, that doesn't work either. Isn't there a configuration file that is executed every time X starts?
X is running btw - `ps aux | grep X` shows one process `/usr/bin/X` running.

Comment: I _think_ that, although not created by default anymore, the X server still respects the /etx/X11/xorg.conf file. Have you tried creating  one and setting a resolution there?

Answer (score 2):

X isn't running or just Xfce?

If there is a live X session, try this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

And then:

```
xrandr -s 0
```

This will reset it to default resolution. Also, you can chose your own resolution:

```
xrandr -s 800x600
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to write that `xrandr -s 0` and `xrandr -s 800x600` doesn't work in the console like `xrandr` to display current configuration. It says `Can't open display`. I'll edit that in my question.

Comment: Which graphic driver are you using?

Comment: VMware tools. I'll edit what your new suggestion changes...

Comment: Try running this: `export XAUTHORITY=/home/<user>/.Xauthority` and than back to the `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and `xrandr -s 0`

Comment: Doesn't work either. Same error as last try. And /home/<user>/.Xauthority doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

xrandr didn't work for this problem. 
After switching to console 1 (ctrl-alt-f1) 
`sudo vi /.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`
change wrong resolution to 800x600
reset/restart